# Using results outside of async function

Tags: asynchronous

sorry if I ask this question here, but tried a lot of things and wasn't able to solve this problem.

I am using this [Library](https://github.com/EdgeVerve/feel), I ran the example and all is good but when I
try to use the results outside the scope of the async function. like this:

```
let x;

const payload = {"Traffic":99,"Growth":9,"Transactions":9,"Weight":33};

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    decisionTable.execute_decision_table("Volumetrics", 
    decision_table,payload,  (err, results)  => {  
        resolve(results);   
    });
});

 x = promise.then(
    result =>{return (result) } 
);

console.log (x);
```

always got  this: `Promise { <pending> }` rather than the json object

I  guess is my ignorance about promises and async functions.  Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd only be able to use it inside the function passed to `then()` like so:

```js
promise.then(
    result => console.log(result) 
);
```

If you were going to do other cool stuff, you'd have to do it all in there.

If you don't like how that looks, look into the `async/await` syntax which is more readable in most cases like so:

```js
let x = await promise;

console.log (x);
```

Comment: Oookay, I was afraid about this answer, it confirms that. Thank you.